# unable to set input method as ibus in gnome-language-selector

Tags: 11.10, gnome, ibus, input-language, language-support

I want to be able to type in Hindi  and want to set input method as ibus in gnome-language-selector window as shown on this blog
http://www.pinyinjoe.com/images/ubuntu/1104/Language-Support.jpg

How ever each time when I select input method as ibus and close the window I log out and login again.Now check the ibus window preferences as in this snapshot

https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5704526930860552098

the options to Hindi which should come as shown in this snapshot 
http://www.muktware.com/sites/default/files/images/applications/ibus-install-3.jpg
 is missing in my machine. I use Ubuntu 11.10 and I do not use Unity. I am using gnome which was installed using

```
   aptitude install gnome-session-fallback
```

The language support for  Hindi is already enabled in gnome-language-selector window.
What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of Googling and continuous efforts to resolve this problem I finally found the solution a package ibus-m17n is also needed.Which installs the required databases for various kind of keyboard maps corresponding to the keys of that language.In above case by installing ibus only the daemon was running but one need to make sure that input langugage database is also installed.
This database is usually in following folder

```
/usr/share/m17n
```

In my case for various input methods to be able to come in drop down menus of ibus preferences following files were needed

```
/usr/share/m17n/hi-inscript.mim    
/usr/share/m17n/hi.lnm             
/usr/share/m17n/hi-remington.mim   
/usr/share/m17n/hi-itrans.mim  
/usr/share/m17n/hi-phonetic.mim    
/usr/share/m17n/hi-typewriter.mim
```

The above files are keymaps for Hindi langugage.Which are needed by the ibus daemon.
Due to absence of above files I was not able to see any input method.A correctly configured ibus with local language database installed will look as follows
https://picasaweb.google.com/107404068162388981296/UnknownAsianLanguage#5705518106929667058